# Regex for either the word null, or a string in double quotes

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm searching a block of text in JSON format. It may be easier to do this another way, but I'm looking to see if this is possible. I'm using `preg_match_all()` in **PHP 7.x**, but this is more of a regex problem.

Sometimes the string in the text is like this **"something":"a string, here!",** and other times it is like this **"something":null,** .

For the first case, this will work...

`/"something":"([^"]*)",/`

For the second case, this will work...

`/"something":null,/`

or

`/"something":([^,]*),/`

Is there a way to match either cases in the same regex?

Something like this doesn't work...

`/"something":"?(null|[^"]*)?"?,/`

And the string can have commas in it, and this doesn't work...

`/"something":(null|[^,]*),/`

Anyone know if this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `json_decode` to parse JSON data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you are using PHP is crucial as you can use

```php
"something":(?|"([^"]*)"|(null)),
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9RzbKQ/1).

*Details*:

- `"something":` - a literal string
- `(?|"([^"]*)"|(null))` - a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html): `"`, Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a `"`, then a `"` or `null` string also captured into Group 1
- `,` - a comma.